# Unable to start IIS Admin service with HResult 0x80010119

Tags: iis

I'm unable to start the IIS admin service, or run IIS Reset.  Whenever I do this I get the following error appear in the event log:

> The IIS Admin service terminated with service-specific error 2147549465 (0x80010119).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by killing the process `inetinfo.exe`. Apparently `iissrv.exe` might also have this effect.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/sajoshi/archive/2006/08/31/733549.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just kill inetinfo.exe via task manager. You might also need to kill all processes relating to IIS, like iissrv.exe. After that iisreset will work again.

Same problem was described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sajoshi/archive/2006/08/31/733549.aspx)

If your problem still exists you might need to specify your system details like .NET version, what version of windows / IIS etc.